# disable JsHint warnings in Intel XDK

Tags: error-handling, warnings, jshint, intel-xdk, adobe-brackets

The brackets editor in Intel XDK is requiring me to do some strange things in my js file. 
If I try to make an ajax call, jshint will give me this error:

```
`$ is not defined (w117).`
```

The only way I've been able to figure out how to get rid of this warning is something that seems obviously wrong to me. I have to declare

```
`var $;`.
```

It's the same thing when I use 'document' to manipulate the DOM. If I don't do

```
`var document;`
```

first I will get another not defined warning. 
What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the JsHint documentation (found here: http://jshint.com/docs/) it'll tell you this

**Configuration**
JSHint comes with a default set of warnings but it was designed to be very configurable. There are three main ways to configure your copy of JSHint: you can either specify the configuration file manually via the --config flag, use a special file .jshintrc or put your config into your projects package.json file under the jshintConfig property. In case of .jshintrc, JSHint will start looking for this file in the same directory as the file that's being linted. If not found, it will move one level up the directory tree all the way up to the filesystem root. (Note that if the input comes from stdin, JSHint doesn't attempt to find a configuration file)

This setup allows you to have different configuration files per project. Place your file into the project root directory and, as long as you run JSHint from anywhere within your project directory tree, the same configuration file will be used.

Configuration file is a simple JSON file that specifies which JSHint options to turn on or off. For example, the following file will enable warnings about undefined and unused variables and tell JSHint about a global variable named MY_GLOBAL.

```
{
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "predef": [ "MY_GLOBAL" ]
}
```

**Inline configuration**
In addition to using configuration files you can configure JSHint from within your files using special comments. These comments start with a label such as jshint or globals (complete list below) and are followed by a comma-separated list of values. For example, the following snippet will enable warnings about undefined and unused variables and tell JSHint about a global variable named MY_GLOBAL.

```
/* jshint undef: true, unused: true */
/* globals MY_GLOBAL */
```

You can use both multi- and single-line comments to configure JSHint. These comments are function scoped meaning that if you put them inside a function they will affect only this function's code.

**Here's more about inline disabling from** https://man42.net/blog/2013/04/jshint-disable-warning-globally/

```
There is two ways to disable a specific warning in JSHint:

Locally, by inserting a comment in your JavaScript file: /*jshint -W099 */

Globally, by editing your .jshintrc file:

{
  /* ... */

  "-W099": false, // disable: Mixed spaces and tabs.
  "-W065": false, // disable: Missing radix parameter.
  "-W015": false, // disable: Expected 'X' to have an indentation at Y instead at Z.
  "-W116": false, // disable: Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the environments you're using in the jshintrc. In your case it looks like you're writing a web app (document) with jQuery ($). Add this to your jshintrc:

```
{
    "browser": true,
    "jquery": true
}
```

You can read more about environments at the [documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/options/).